# Ckeditor 5 Angular 11 integration with custom plugins

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5, angular11

I am trying to add ckeditor5 to my angular project. The classic version works fine but when I try yo build custom builds using online builder (https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) and then followed the guide (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#using-a-custom-ckeditor-5-build). However, when running the project I get this error.

```
core.js:5980 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
    at Object.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:5)
    at Object.push.+z1p (ckeditor.js:5)
    at n (ckeditor.js:5)
    at Module.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:5)
    at n (ckeditor.js:5)
    at push.+z1p (ckeditor.js:5)
    at ckeditor.js:5
    at ckeditor.js:5
    at Object.+z1p (ckeditor.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28289)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:5980
handleError @ core.js:6028
next @ core.js:28901
schedulerFn @ core.js:25666
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:25656
(anonymous) @ core.js:28324
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:364
run @ zone-evergreen.js:123
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:28229
onHandleError @ core.js:28324
handleError @ zone-evergreen.js:368
runGuarded @ zone-evergreen.js:136
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone-evergreen.js:670
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:576
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:552
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:388
onScheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:272
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:378
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:210
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:230
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:847
resolvePromise @ zone-evergreen.js:785
(anonymous) @ zone-evergreen.js:705
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:25
(anonymous) @ research-research-module.js:1
```

Comment: We hit this problem after an upgrade to Angular 11 (running downgraded with Angular JS remnants). In our case we had checked that no custom plugins referenced different versions, that all imports reference /src/ instead of /build as per docs, and we also built the custom build as part of the library to avoid conflicts...the cause was an ng-include left in the template of a component that was migrated to Angular causing a runtime issue